# Limit of two-variable function

Tags: calculus, limits

I must determine whether the following limit exists, and if so its value.

$$ \lim_{(x,y)\to (1,1)} \frac{x-y}{y-1} $$

My thinking is that the fact that the function is undefined along the entire line $y=1$ means that the limit does not exist. Is this correct, or de we allow an entire line to be undefined?

If not, is there a good approach to solving this? The limit seems to be "0/0" from all directions. I can't see how to evaluate it.

Comment: Hint: Try approaching the limit along the x-axis first, then work on the y-axis. If the values are different then the limit does not exist.

Comment: Yes, the function seems to me to be undefined along the entire line y=1. Is this a problem?

Answer (score 3):

If $(x,y)=(1+t, 1+t)$, then $$\lim\frac{x-y}{y-1}=\lim_{t\to0}\frac0t=0$$

If $(x,y)=(1+2t, 1+t)$, then $$\lim\frac{x-y}{y-1}=\lim_{t\to0}\frac tt=1$$

So, the limit do not exists.

Answer (score 3):

Function can be considered on $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{(x,1)\}$. For non existence consider lines $y=x$ and $y=2x-1$. So, we will have
$$\frac{x-y}{y-1} = \frac{x-x}{x-1} = 0 \to 0$$
and
$$\frac{x-y}{y-1} = \frac{2x-1-x}{2x-1-1} = \frac{x-1}{2(x-1)}=\frac 12 \to \frac 12$$

Answer (score 3):

$X:=x-1$; $Y:=y-1$,  $Y \not =0$, and

consider $\lim_{(X, Y) \rightarrow (0,0)}\dfrac{X-Y}{Y};$

$1)Let X=0, Y \rightarrow 0;$

$L_1=-1.$

$2)X=Y$, $Y \rightarrow 0,$

$L_2=0.$

Hence?

Comment: Perfect, beautiful.

Comment: @Orm.Thank you:))

Answer (score -2):

$\frac{x-y}{y-1} =-1 +\frac{x-1}{y-1} $.  $z=-1 +\frac{x-1}{y-1} $ would show a singularity where y=1=x, so the limit would be indeterminate as you are dividing $0$ by $0$.